# How to restore to a previous save?

Tags: simcity-2013

I had my best city ever running smoothly, but forgot the game was running when I left to do some things. A few hours later I came back to find my entire city had been destroyed by fire.

How do I restore to a previous save? I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply can't. There are no savegames, just the cloud. It's like an MMO where you can't save and reload later on.